# What is the variant bā character for 巴掌?

Tags: character-identification

I'm working through the entry for 耳巴 in《四川方言词语续考》and I don't have my paper copy around.

The problem is I only have my crappy OCR'd digital version which is giving me �� where a proper character should be.

Here's the part I'm struggling over:

> 或作“耳��”。民國十八年《榮縣志·禮俗》： “《說文》： ‘獸足謂之番。’ 附袁切。古無輕唇音，番讀如班，今音如板， 手掌謂手番， 足掌曰足番，雙聲轉��。《說文》： ‘��， ��擊 也。 ’ 今��掌、耳��，北人强以刮字當之， 非也。”

A variant bā character for 巴掌 I figured would be quite easy to find, but nothing is showing up in searches for `北人强以刮字當之`, etc.

The only variant I know for 巴 is  but I can't seem to find any《說文》material for .

Can anyone fill in the blanks (read: question marks)? What is the variant bā character for 巴掌?

Comment: Could it be '芭' / ba1/ (plantain)? As in 芭蕉叶 (plantain leaf ) which  stretched out like an open palm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「」 fulfils the statement `《說文》：‘��，��擊也。’` (check the Shuowen entry on zdic), and also everything else.

> **耳巴**，或作 “耳「」”。民國十八年《榮縣志·禮俗》：“《說文》： ‘獸足謂之番。’ 附袁切。古無輕唇音，番讀如班，今音如板， 手掌謂手番， 足掌曰足番，雙聲轉「」。《說文》： ‘「」，「」（批）擊也。’ 今「」掌、耳「」，北人强以刮字當之， 非也。”

Note,

- Zdict lists「」with the third tone, not the first tone (bā). I can't confirm with an external resource about this tone.
- `北人强以刮字當之` is saying that there are multiple words for「耳巴」, like「[耳光](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%80%B3%E5%85%89)」,「[耳摑](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%80%B3%E6%8E%B4)」,「[耳刮子](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%80%B3%E5%88%AE%E5%AD%90)」, etc.

Comment: I'll double check with my paper copy later but I think you're totally right.